# php + sql hierarchical array result

Tags: php, sql

I'm using php + sql. Now I've a table like this:

```
user_id  word
-------------
 u1       w1
 u1       w2
 u2       w1
 u2       w3
```

And I want to query the database for the data grouped by user. 
The desired result should be a hierarchical array, like

```
array("u1"=>array("0"=>"w1', "1"=>"w2"), "u2"=>array("0"=>"w1", "1"=>"w3"))
```

How can I do that?

## Edit

I have only wrote some ordinary sql's like

```
select * from DB order by user
```

And I'm afraid it's nothing close.

Comment: Have you wrote any SQL query yet for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it, I haven't checked but please try,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1 GROUP BY user_id");
While($data = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
     $get_data[] = $data ;
}

if($get_data){
    foreach($get_data as $val){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE user_id = '".$val['user_id']."'");
        while($data_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $val['user_id'];
            $res[] = $data_new ;
        }
        $userID = $val['user_id'] ;
        $array[][$userID] = $res ;
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Note that there is another answer by @NullVoid that has a better performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example but you MUST USE PDO instead of mysql_*

Try below one. It will solve your problem

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblwords";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $userId = $row['user_id'];
    $arr[$userId][] = $row['word'];
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [u1] => Array
        (
            [0] => w1
            [1] => w2
        )

    [u2] => Array
        (
            [0] => w1
            [1] => w3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer is the same as Purushottam's and I will select his as the answer for he seems to be a new guy here. And +1 for your elegant illustration.

Comment: Definitely. We should encourage new guys. I am glad that your problem has been resolved. I just read his answer and my answer is more accurate in case of performance. I have used only one loop while he's executing loop 3 times.

Comment: That's right. I've to confess that your answer is more elegant in both script and performance.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but as i know you can't.

but you can get the result like this;

```
SELECT user_id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT word
        ORDER BY wordDESC SEPARATOR ',') as words
FROM table_name
GROUP BY user_id
```

result;

```
user_id | words
  u1    | w1,w2
  u2    | w1,w3
```